# Cannot correctly parse my object from JSONreturned from my C# Web API

Tags: c#, json.net, webapi

I have searched until my eyes are bleeding but alas no answers.

I have a class called Booking.

```
public class Booking
    {     

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? ClientName { get; set; }
    }
```

The API method is

```
[HttpGet]        
        public async Task<JsonResult> Get(int id)
        {
            Booking? booking = await _bookingRepository.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (booking == null)
            {
                return new JsonResult(NotFound());
            }
            return new JsonResult(Ok(booking));
        }
```

The Client is

```
protected static async Task<Booking?> GetAsync<Booking>(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7139/api/HotelBooking?id=5");
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                string msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return default(Booking);
            }
            else if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Booking? booking = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Booking>(msg);
                //Booking? booking = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Booking>();
                
                return booking;
            }           
            else
            {
                string msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
        }
```

The value in msg is

```
{
  "Value": {
    "Id": 5,
    "RoomNumber": 100,
    "ClientName": "Nelms, Anthony"
  },
  "Formatters": [],
  "ContentTypes": [],
  "DeclaredType": null,
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

The result:  I have a Booking object that is instantiated by the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` line of code, but all three values are missing.  The string is null and the two ints are zero.

I believe the problem is that the section "Value" is "hiding" my data. I am not sure how to read the data from `response.Content`.

This is my first attempt at Http.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I would try return `Ok(booking)` instead of `JsonResult(Ok(booking))` - see if that works. Seems like wrapping the return in a JsonResult is also creating a new type of `OK` object here.

Comment: Your object model doesn't seem to match your JSON. Your JSON contains a root object, which has a `Value` property matching `Booking`, but you do not have this root class. Either create the root object, or change the API so that it returns the correct data, as @topsail suggested.

Comment: @Charlieface, you are correct in that the Booking poco and the value returned don't match.  But the question was or at least in my head the question was how do I parse the information returned or how do I cause the information to be returned in the form that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing `msg` with `msg.Result` in below line?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Booking>(msg.Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [the suggestion from @TopSail in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860550/cannot-correctly-parse-my-object-from-json-returned-from-my-c-sharp-web-api/72860645?noredirect=1#comment128691954_72860550), and it worked:

> Well, I would try return `Ok(booking)` instead of `JsonResult(Ok(booking))` - see if that works. Seems like wrapping the return in a `JsonResult` is also creating a new type of `OK` object here. –

Before I read your suggestion I simply returned the object as follows:

```
return booking;
```

That worked.

However, I like your suggestion better. I implemented your suggestion as follows:

```
return Ok(booking);
```

This also worked.